# Splitting an update operation into chunks, with commits

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am running a process acting on a returned list like this

```
MATCH p=(Item{name:'x'})-[r:RELATED_TO]->(w:item) 
where r.relatedness > 0.25
[PERFORM CALCS AND UPDATE w]
```

The initial `MATCH` only brings back about 100 nodes, but the perform calcs step is an n^2 operation, with a reasonably large n. Each `[PERFORM...]`  step can be performed independently. The whole thing might take a day to run.

I would like to break this up so that it commits after each `[PERFORM... ]` step. This way in the event of a failure I can start up from where I left off.

In SQL server I might store the results of the initial `MATCH` to a table, and work through it using a `CURSOR`, marking off completed rows as I went

How can I do something analogous in Neo4J?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a concept:

1) Save the result of the first query:

```
WITH 'x' as itemName
MERGE (T:SavedQueryResult {name: itemName})
WITH itemName, T
MATCH (:item {name: itemName})-[r:RELATED_TO]->(w:item) WHERE r.relatedness > 0.25
MERGE (I:SavedID {id: ID(w), processed: false})
MERGE (T)-[:hasResult]->(I)
```

2) And execute a sequence of queries:

```
WITH 'x' as itemName
MATCH (T:SavedQueryResult {name: itemName})-[:hasResult]->(I:SavedID {processed: false})
MATCH (w:item) WHERE ID(w) = I.id
[PERFORM CALCS AND UPDATE w]
SET I.processed = true
```

3) To process the saved results, you can use the [`apoc.periodic.commit`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_apoc_periodic_commit) from the [`APOC library`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/).

Comment: Thanks very much. Will give this a try. Does starting with "As a concept" mean you think this is not the best way of doing what I want to do? (or am I reading a subtext that isn't there)

Comment: @DanBennett The `concept` means that in relation to your case the solution can be this way. In my projects I solve similar problems in the same way.

Comment: Just to note, we recommend `apoc.periodic.iterate()` instead of `apoc.periodic.commit()` for batching operations. They may be similar, but `apoc.periodic.iterate()` tends to be more efficient, and handles the batching implicitly (though you can change the batch size if needed). With `apoc.periodic.commit()`, you need to explicitly perform the limit in your query and ensure you return the count of updates, otherwise you risk writing a bad query which may hang.